# WebMatrix webforms with database + code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, webforms, webmatrix

I've been searching for information how to manipulate with database in **WebMatrix** when making webforms, but I only found code that wasn't relevant - wanting me to work with <s>.cshtml</s> files or something like that, when I have **.aspx** file as a webform...

Anyone got some relevant links or help?

Also I've been wondering why does WebMatrix not support code behind or if it does how can I make it work?

Adding `CodeBehind="MyWebForm.aspx.cs"` in 1st line does not compile that code..

Answer (score 0):

WebMatrix was not designed to fully support Web Forms development. From that point of view, it is little more than a text editor with a bit of code completion built in. You should use [Visual Studio Express For Web](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-web) instead. It is free (requires registration) but is the correct tool for your job.

Comment: Well I thought that when it is said to support asp.net(http://www.microsoft.com/Web/webmatrix/asp.aspx) that I could use it with webforms.. but guess not so I'm just back to using VS.